# Powershell DISM Progression bar

Tags: powershell

I have a problem, I am building a powershell script to restore / save wim images using the DISM command.
So I use a winform interface, with a progress bar.
However, I can't find a way to send the% information for my progress bar.

Currently I have done tests with my DISM command in fact for example >> c: \ test and I manage to recover the% but I cannot do them simultaneously.

Here is the code, do you have any idea?

```
     Foreach ( $line in "c:\test.txt" ) 
{ 
   $content = Get-Content -Path 'c:\test.txt'
   $content
   $count = ($content | Select-String -Pattern '%' -AllMatches)
   $PCcomplete = $count.Count-1
}
Dism /Capture-Image /ImageFile:$chemin /CaptureDir:$choixlettre\ /Name:$nom /Compress:max /LogLevel:4 >> c:\test.txt
```

Comment: Is `write-progress` not giving you the desired results?

Comment: can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it's work ! But my progression bar stop at 96...97 the count forget some number..

```
$sb = [scriptblock]::Create("dism /apply-image /imagefile:$chemin /index:1 /applydir:t: /LogLevel:4 >>t:\test.txt")
        $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb
        #
        $pccomplete = 0
        $pccomplete1 = 0
        # Boucle
        while((Get-Job | Where-Object {$_.State -ne "Completed"}).Count -gt 0)
        {               
                $content = get-content -Path 't:\test.txt' 
                $count = ($content | Select-String -Pattern '%' -AllMatches)
                $PCcomplete = $count.Count
                start-sleep -Second 2
                if( $pccomplete1 -ne $pccomplete )
                {
                    $pccomplete1 = $pccomplete
                    $richtextBox_history.AppendText("$PCcomplete`n")
                    $progressBar1.Value = $pccomplete
                }
```